# Align select input and Snooze button in one line in UWP toast notification using toast.xml

Tags: c#, xml, uwp

How can I align select input and Snooze button in one line in UWP toast notification using toast.xml? I am using Visual Studio to do this.

We can do this with text Input but not with Selection Input.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How can I align select input and Snooze button in one line in UWP toast notification using toast.xml?

I'm afraid you can't do it, the default [ToastSelectionBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-schema#toastselectionbox) will fill a row, so the snooze button will skip to the new line automatically.

For your scenario, we suggest you use `Messaging.xml` to replace that could place a button and input in one line. For more detail please refer to [Toast content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=builder-syntax) document. And this [Notification visualizer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/notifications-visualizer/9nblggh5xsl1?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) app.